# How do I add next/prev controls to a blog?

Tags: templating

I want to show the latest blog post on the blog/index.html page of my blog which I have done. I now want to display a link to the next post.

Likewise, when I click a blog entry's url I want to add next / prev controls to the blog/_detail.html page.

What is a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are other questions to this topic already, blairrorani! See ['pagination'](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagination) or ['previous-next'](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previous-next) tags. I think this can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: [How do I build a pagination nav?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/pagination-nav)

Comment: Thank you. That answered my question. Must have been searching using different key words.

Comment: You're welcome! There's a lot of useful information at: http://buildwithcraft.com/help